# Comparing two lists, one of them can change (depending tha DataFrame) and add a new column with the results

Tags: python, pandas

The lists ( 2 o more) to compare with the DataFrame (column A) can change depending tha data of the column B

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [['10', '20', '30', '40'],['50', '60', '70', '80'],['90','100','110','120'],'B': ['X','Y','Z']})
    
    findA = ['10','25', '20','35']
    findB = ['60','85]
        .
        .
        .
    findX
    
    
                      A  B
0      [10, 20, 30, 40]  X
1      [50, 60, 70, 80]  Y
2   [90, 100, 110, 120]  Z
```

This will be the desired behavior

If the data of column B is 'X' then compare findA list with column A and add the diference (findA) to the column C

If the data of column B is 'Y' then compare findB list with column A and add the diference (findB) to the column C

else NaN

```
                      A  B              C
0      [10, 20, 30, 40]  X    ['25','35']
1      [50, 60, 70, 80]  Y         ['85']
2   [90, 100, 110, 120]  Z            NaN
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For improve performance is filtered rows and processing only matched values by masks, then is created new column by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with difference of sets:

```
m1 = df['B'].eq('X')
df.loc[m1, 'C'] =  df.loc[m1, 'A'].apply(lambda x: list(set(findA) - set(x)))
m2 = df['B'].eq('Y')
df.loc[m2, 'C'] =  df.loc[m2, 'A'].apply(lambda x: list(set(findB) - set(x)))

print (df)
                     A  B         C
0     [10, 20, 30, 40]  X  [35, 25]
1     [50, 60, 70, 80]  Y      [85]
2  [90, 100, 110, 120]  Z       NaN
```

More dynamic solution:

```
d = {'X': findA, 'Y': findB}
   
for k, v in d.items():      
    m = df['B'].eq(k)
    df.loc[m, 'C'] =  df.loc[m, 'A'].apply(lambda x: list(set(v) - set(x)))

print (df)
                     A  B         C
0     [10, 20, 30, 40]  X  [35, 25]
1     [50, 60, 70, 80]  Y      [85]
2  [90, 100, 110, 120]  Z       NaN
```

Solution with [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) is possible, but here `apply` processing all values, so if large data it should be slowier:

```
m1 = df['B'].eq('X')
m2 = df['B'].eq('Y')
a =  df['A'].apply(lambda x: list(set(findA) - set(x)))
b =  df['A'].apply(lambda x: list(set(findB) - set(x)))

df['C'] = np.select([m1, m2], [a, b], np.nan)
print (df)
                     A  B         C
0     [10, 20, 30, 40]  X  [35, 25]
1     [50, 60, 70, 80]  Y      [85]
2  [90, 100, 110, 120]  Z       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first build a temporary dataframe to *link* the `findx` lists to the values of column `B` and merge it into `df`:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], 'find': [findA, findB, findC]})

df['C'] = df.merge(tmp, on='B').apply(lambda x: list(set(x['find']) - set(x['A'])), axis=1)
```

With a reasonable `findC` it gives:

```
                     A  B         C
0     [10, 20, 30, 40]  X  [35, 25]
1     [50, 60, 70, 80]  Y      [85]
2  [90, 100, 110, 120]  Z        []
```

If you really need a NaN instead of the empty list, just do:

```
df.loc[df['C'].apply(len) == 0, 'C'] = np.nan
```